# Cannot create empty folder in gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

It sounds confusing, but...

how to create a simple empty folder in target folder with the help of gradle without copying artifacts and using "into()" method?

Is it a simple way to do it not using native Groovy, but Gradle?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why don't you just try:

```
new File('lol').mkdirs()
```

With gradle:

```
project.file('lol').mkdirs()
```

Docs are [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: get no idea why i'm not able to google this information

Answer (score 8):

Now `mkdir` is built-in:

```
project.mkdir "${someDir}/subdir"
```